# Angular 2+ ngFor using index variable as array pointer

Tags: angular, ngfor

Is it possible to use the index variable as an array pointer?

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[i]; let i = index">
     <td>{{item}}</td>
  </div>
```

I don't get any errors, but nothing is displayed. 
I've tried calling a function in the component.ts as shown below, but this led to a lot of other issues.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of messageSplit[incrementArray()]">
     <td>{{item}}</td>
 </div> 

 incrementArray() {
     return this.counter++;
 }
```

Here are the relevant methods in my component.ts file incase needed for further insight into the issue

```
messageSplit = new Array;

loadMessages() {
this.messageSplit = [];
const currentUserId = +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid;
this.userService.getMessages(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid,
  this.messageContainer)
  .do(messages => {
    _.each(messages, (message: Message) => {

      if (this.messageContainer !== 'unread') {
        if (this.compareArray(message) !== true) {
          this.splitMessages(message);
        }
      }
      if (message.isRead === false && message.recipientId === currentUserId) 
  {
        this.userService.markAsRead(currentUserId, message.id);
      }
    });
  }, error => {
    console.log('');
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.messageSplit);
    this.splitReady = true;
  })
  .subscribe((res: Message[]) => {
    this.messages = res;
  });
}

compareArray(message) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.messageSplit.length; i++) {
    if (message.content !== null) {
      if (this.messageSplit[i] === message.content.split(',')) {
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if (count > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

splitMessages(message) {
  if (message.content !== null) {
    this.messageSplit.push(message.content.split(','));
  }
}

increment() {
  return this.counter++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your goal with that? You can nest `*ngFor's`

Comment: Your edit provides zero clarity. We need to see a `console.log` of `messageSplit` - so we can see the actual data it contains.

Answer (score 0):

ngFor works only against an array. messageSplit[i] will return you only one element and you will not be able to iterate through it (unless messageSplit[i] returns an array). Please provide details of messageSplit. It will help to answer the question.

Comment: messageSplit[i] does return an array.